# cannot access the divs after appending into another html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
  </div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
  <div id="div4">
    <div id="div5">
      <div id="div6">
      </div>
      <div id="divcontent">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divButtons">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

I have the above divs, as a html file, that gets appended into another html file.
after appending this file, I want to append some buttons into the `divButtons` and some text into the `divcontent`.
Somehow I am unable to achieve it.
I have tried:

```
$("#div1").children('#divButtons').append('<button></button>');
$('#divButtons').append('<button></button>')
```

if I am doing anything wrong, please guide me.
Thanks

Comment: What have you already tried? What is not working?

Comment: The question is updated with ways I have already tried, Thanks

Comment: `children('divButtons')` replace to `children('#divButtons')`

Comment: I don't understand the down votes!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.find` instead of `.children`.

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a **single** level down the DOM tree

<sup>https://api.jquery.com/children/</sup>

```js
$("#div1").find('#divButtons').append('<button></button>');
$('#divButtons').append('<button></button>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
  </div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
  <div id="div4">
    <div id="div5">
      <div id="div6">
      </div>
      <div id="divcontent">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divButtons">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

**Note** Since `divButtons` is `id` you don't need to use `children` or `find` because you know it's unique.

Comment: `find(id)` is redundant in the first place since ID's must be unique

Comment: @charlietfl I just followed his code. Of course he didn't need to use the `find` anyway.. I was updated my answer. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` instead of `children` and include you script in document,ready function. or instead just use `$('#divButton')` ans `$(#divContent')` since ID must be unique

```js
$(function(){
$("#div1").find('#divButtons').append('<button>hello</button>');
$('#divButtons').append('<button>hello</button>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
  </div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
  <div id="div4">
    <div id="div5">
      <div id="div6">
      </div>
      <div id="divcontent">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divButtons">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```